# when I use Angular Material date picker It's stop to show my Page

Tags: angular, angular-material

After adding angular meterial package in my angular project I use bellow code to use date picker . But when I use date picker code any HTML page it's hide my total page. I'm New in angular so, I'm not familiar with this type of angular behavior.
**account.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AccountRoutingModule } from './account-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TestAccountComponent } from './test-account/test-account.component';
import { FogetPasswordComponent } from './foget-password/foget-password.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    TestAccountComponent,
    FogetPasswordComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AccountRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { }
```

component.html

```
    <div><mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
      <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I am new in angular. I can't Identify why this code hide my Page?

Comment: Add it in your list of providers in app.module.ts: `...imports: [ MatDatepickerModule], providers: [ MatDatepickerModule]...` You may also need to import MatNativeDateModule.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported MatIconModule ?
Because you are using mat icon in the mat form field

If not

import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

imports:[......., MatIconModule]